# XPATH - grab content from DIV with nestled a text

Tags: xpath

Can anyone help me with this? I cannot grab the 'Blue Shoes' text from this div no matter what I try! Been over an hour now and still cannot work it out. Tried:

```
//div[@class='breadcrumbs']/text(
//div[@class='breadcrumbs']
//div[@class='breadcrumbs']/div
```

Nothing seems to work. Any help MUCH appreciated.

```
<div class="breadcrumbs"><a href="http://www.example.aspx" style="color:#e16a58;">Home</a>/Blue Shoes</div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Can it be that the XHTML is invalid? "Sweets & Candy" should really be "Sweets &amp; Candy"

Comment: In this case maybe, but this is just an example. There are hundreds of other pages with no "&" sign. Will change example! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
//div[@class='breadcrumbs']/text()
```

should give you what you need in this case - it will select the set of all text nodes that lie directly under the breadcrumbs div. if you want to specifically target the one at the end (e.g. if there's more than two levels of breadcrumb and there's another text node for, say, a slash between two `a` elements) then the slightly more specific

```
//div[@class='breadcrumbs']/text()[last()]
```

may work better.

If this doesn't work then there are two other possibilities I can think of. Firstly, the HTML DOM uses upper case for element names, and since XPath is case-sensitive you may find you need `//DIV` instead of `//div`. Or maybe there's a namespace issue - if your document has an `xmlns="..."` on the root element then that puts your div elements in a namespace, and unprefixed names in xpath refer to nodes in *no* namespace. To select namespaced nodes you have to bind a prefix to the corresponding namespace URI and then use the prefix in your expressions (`//xhtml:div`). Exactly how you go about mapping prefixes depends on what library/tool/language you're using to execute the xpath queries.

Comment: That doesn't work either. Maybe it's the pages and the way they are rendered. They are using some overly complicated javascript stuff. Thanks in any case.